# pass all current variables to function in python

Tags: python, function, debugging, parameter-passing

I want to call a function in Python that allows me to access all current variables during execution (for debugging). Something like this:

```
def interruptWithTerminal():
    interruptchoice = ""
    while interruptchoice != "Y":
        interruptchoice = raw_input("print what variable? (Y to continue script): ")
        try:
            print eval(interruptchoice)
        except:
            print "Error"
```

My problem is that I don't get access to the variables at the point where I call this function. Any ideas?

Comment: May be you're looking for [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: import pdb    pdb.set_trace()

Comment: Usually I run `python -i file.py` to run your file and open the interactive shell aftwards. Then you can access everythign directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CPython, you can find the caller's frame with

```
frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
```

and access its locals and globals with `frame.f_locals`, and `frame.f_globals`.

---

```
import inspect
def interruptWithTerminal():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    while True:
        interruptchoice = raw_input("print what variable? (Press Enter to continue): ")
        if not interruptchoice.strip(): break
        try:
            print eval(interruptchoice, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
        except:
            print "Error"
```

Since `Y` could be a variable, perhaps let the user press `Enter` to break out of the loop instead.

Comment: grumble, grumble ... I was just about to post something about inspecting the stack frame.  Nicely done :)  (+1 from me)

Comment: @mgilson: Just lucky this time :)

Comment: Although, for what it's worth, `pdb.set_trace()` is probably better than any half-baked solution we could come up with.  But, in any event, it's nice to know how `pdb.set_trace()` is most likely implemented :)

Comment: @unutbu: thanks! Works like a charm, and good pointer on the Y variable

Comment: and you guys are right, the pdb.set_trace() also does exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> var = True
>>> import __main__ as main
>>> for attr in dir(main):
    print str(attr), '=', repr(getattr(main, attr))


__builtins__ = <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>
__doc__ = None
__name__ = '__main__'
__package__ = None
attr = 'attr'
main = <module '__main__' (built-in)>
var = True
```

You can make a dictionary of all of the variables like this:

```
>>> var = True
>>> import __main__ as main
>>> d = {attr:getattr(main, attr) for attr in dir(main)}
>>> d
{'attr': 'var', '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'var': True, '__name__': '__main__', 'main': <module '__main__' (built-in)>, '__doc__': None}
```